# xstring StrSubstitute and table

Tags: tables, macros, xstring

I got a problem with `xstring` `\StrSubstitute` in combination with a table. I would like to replace newline (`\\`) in a variable with the `\newline` command to generate a second line in a paragraphed table cell. Therefore I got the following code, which works fine for the first output (if I put `\addr` to the left column), but for the second output in the right column I get a

```
Undefined control sequence error
```

I have no idea how to fix this and why the first output works but not the second.

Thanks for any help.

edit: added MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.27cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xstring}

\def\address{Test123\\Test234}

\providecommand{\test}[1][0pt]{%
Test1 & Test\newline Test2\tabularnewline
\ifx\@empty\address\else
\saveexpandmode\expandarg
\StrSubstitute{\address}{\empty\\}{\empty\newline}[\addr]%
\restoreexpandmode
\addr & Address \tabularnewline
Address    & \addr   \tabularnewline
\fi
}   
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}|p{2cm}}
\test
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that assignments within cells of a table are local to that cell. So, one way around that is to define a macro to generate the desired result:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.27cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xstring}

\def\address{Test123\\Test234}

\newcommand{\addrGlobal}{%
    \ifx\@empty\address\else
    \saveexpandmode\expandarg
    \StrSubstitute{\address}{\empty\\}{\empty\newline}[\addr]%
    \restoreexpandmode\addr%
}%

\providecommand{\test}[1][0pt]{%
Test1 & Test\newline Test2\tabularnewline
\addrGlobal & Address \tabularnewline
Address    &  \addrGlobal   \tabularnewline
\fi
}   
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}|p{2cm}}
\test
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```